# Могу ли я использовать бесплатную версию карт яндекса?

Tags: веб-программирование

Я хочу купить готовое решение - сайт. Каждый год использования я буду платить разработчикам за лицензию. Мои пользователи за регистрацию мне ничего платить не будут. Никакой оплаты за сайт, тоже вносить не будут. На сайте будет возможность оплаты коммунальных услуг. Карта будет использоваться для отображения объектов, которые находятся в обслуживании. Доступ к этой странице будет у всех пользователей интернета.

Answer (score 1):

[Официальная документация от Яндекс](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/)

> Пользоваться API Яндекс.Карт можно бесплатно, если соблюдать условия:
>
> 1) Бесплатная версия API предназначена только для сайтов или
>   приложений, доступ к которым может получить любой пользователь
>   интернета. Если есть регистрация, она должна быть доступной всем
>   желающим. Бесплатная версия API не предназначена для проектов с
>   ограниченным доступом, например, когда он раздается по приглашениям
>   или открыт только для сотрудников внутри компании.
>
> 2) Бесплатная версия API не подходит для проектов, которые требуют
>   платы за регистрацию или приобретения лицензии.